# Skip Airflow Tasks on Certain Days

Tags: airflow

I am looking to organize functionally similar tasks within a single dag. I know this is not common practice, but I am looking to skip tasks on certain days. 2 of the 4 tasks should run every day; the remaining 2 tasks will run once a week. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Turns out 1) you can't set the task list based on a condition which checks the date. 2) you cant pass `schedule_interval` at the task level.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Is it an option editing the code of the two tasks that need to run once a week so they only run if `today` is... dunno... Monday? (for instance) I suppose another possibility would be looking into a [branch operator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/dags.html#concepts-branching) so the branch "dies" if `today` is not Monday? Maybe? Would that be an option?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [BranchDayOfWeekOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/weekday.html) just for that.

```py
everyday_task_1 = EmptyOperator(task_id="everyday_task_1")
everyday_task_2 = EmptyOperator(task_id="everyday_task_2")
once_a_week_task_1 = EmptyOperator(task_id="once_a_week_task_1")
once_a_week_task_2 = EmptyOperator(task_id="once_a_week_task_2")

branch = BranchDayOfWeekOperator(
    task_id="make_choice",
    follow_task_ids_if_true=["once_a_week_task_1", "once_a_week_task_2"],
    follow_task_ids_if_false=None,
    week_day="Monday",
)

everyday_task_1 >> everyday_task_2 >> branch >> once_a_week_task_1 >> once_a_week_task_2
```

Comment: Thanks! I found this shortly after I posted. This will come in handy, but strange they had the foresight to create a weekly `Branch` but not a monthly one which is also something I'd have use for.

Comment: If you check operator's [source code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/operators/weekday.py) you'll be able to easily write your own monthly one :)